# Move multiple Azure Wiki pages while keeping cross references

Tags: azure, azure-devops-wiki

How do I quickly move multiple Azure wiki pages to a different subpage, while keeping wiki links?

For example:

```
food/
├── carrot
├── peach
└── tomato
```

Should become:

```
food/
├── fruits
│   └── peach
└── vegetables
    ├── carrot
    └── tomato
```

I am able to drag and drop one page to another a location. Azure then checks for broken links before moving ("Loading broken wiki page links") and auto replaces them. This "auto-replace" takes quite a while, so moving tens or hundreds of pages one by one is a pain.

Cloning the wiki repo, I am able to quickly move many pages using a file manager.
However, there is no check for broken wiki links. Hence, a link to `food/tomato` breaks, once it is located in `food/vegetables/tomato`.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy answer for this. You might consider developing your own utility to recurse the locally cloned repository (.md files) and apply your edits/changes.